# Python OLS window_type rolling not working with statsmodels.api

Tags: regression

I'm using the statsmodels.api to do an OLS but i noticed that the rolling function is not working.
I have a dataframe with 2800 rows and i wrote the following code :

```
model = sm.OLS(Y, X, window=252, window_type='rolling', intercept = 'true')
```

But the result i get is for the 2800 rows instead of the rolling window of 252 rows. Can someone help me? Also the option "intercept = 'true' does not seem to work.
thanks,